# validation rule not working

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

Please have a look at this validation array in my cakephp app for model Unit:

```
public $validate=array(
    'type'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
        'message'=>'You must choose what type of property this is.'
    ),
    'unitnum'=>array(
        'rule'=>array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 -\'.\/&]*$/i'),
        'message'=>'Must be the name or number of your unit.'
    ),
    'unit_website'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'specials'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'rates'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'book'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'contact'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    )
);
```

Every rule EXCEPT the one for 'specials' works.  I thought I maybe misspelled it in my validation array, my form or my database field, but it's spelled correctly.
So then I tried moving it around in the array.  That didn't work.  I tried deleting it and rewriting it by hand.  No go.

I thought, well maybe the file  /tmp/cache/models/cake_model_defaults_units was to blame.  I deleted that, and still it doesn't work.

Then I verified that the uploaded copy of my Unit.php model definition was the most current, up to date version.  Yep, it is.

Even weirder, I tried adding new fields like 'foo' and 'bar' into my database, then giving them validation rules (like 'url' or 'numeric').  Every single time, no matter what I enter in the form fields, their validation does NOT fail, and cake updates my database.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried renaming the field? say "specials_website"

Comment: Maybe you could verify if all data are the same in `beforeValidate()` method with `debug()`.

Comment: @pollirrata, tried that with no success.

Comment: @Paulo Rodrigues, could you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: In your model, override the `beforeValidate` method just with debug for check data submited, like this: http://pastebin.com/VcDF5n7y

Comment: I never had a beforeValidate method defined in my model, so I added this, but how do I see the results?

Comment: Because even though I added this to my model, when I enter invalid data into the 'specials' input, the field validates and it updates my database.  I see no debugging output.

Comment: Because it's defined in extended class, you will just override. Now, just submit your form and you will see the debug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9243/discussion-between-heather-walters-and-paulo-rodrigues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was, after help from @Paulo Rodrigues, that I had TWO copies of my model on my server (ouch!).  Deleted them both and installed a fresh copy of the correct model.